# Remove numbers from url with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have just migrated a site from Joomla to WordPress, everything works, but I need a rule to remove date+time block from url.

Old URLs were like this

```
domain.tld/201009081045/category/subcategory/article.html
```

I have removed .html part with this:

```
#BEGIN sjebani linkovi fix
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

#301 da izbaci html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
#END sjebani linkovi fix
```

And I tried removing the first number block with this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /^[0-9]{6-13}$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

My logic is to find string that has only numbers is longer than 6 chars and shorter than 13, because I need date archives active (domain.tld/2008/12/01, etc...).

How can I remove first number block with mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is a little wonky and you need to match everything that's after the date in order for your `$1` backreference to work:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[0-9]{6,13}/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Changed {6-13} to {6,13} and it works like a charm. 
Thanx :)

Comment: @SeeBeen sorry, I copy and pasted without looking at it carefully